# On an Ubuntu server, how do I call "sudo reload myproject" from a python script in Flask

Tags: python, ubuntu, nginx, flask, gunicorn

I followed the tutorial here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04 and created a Flask app hosted on an Ubuntu server on Digital Ocean. To update the website, I need to ssh into my cloud server and call "sudo reload myproject" from the command line. I would like to automate this and have the python code in Flask call this command every time it gets a post request.

I tried using os.system('sudo reload myproject') but that does not work. How would I use Flask to reload the project?

in /etc/sudoers.d/myOverrides.tmp, I have the following line:

user ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL

the code in my flask module:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import os 

@application.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def hello():
    os.system('sudo reload halo')
    if (request.method == 'POST'):
        print 'post request'
        os.system('sudo reload halo')
        return "<h1>reloaded</h1>"  
    else:
        return "<h1>default</h1>"
```

When I type in "sudo reload halo" on the command line, it reloads without a problem. I would like the Flask application to execute the same command.

Comment: Propably you have to type password to use sudo and os.system will not allow you to do that. The easiest way is to configure sudoers file to allow this one command as passwordlesss.

Comment: Hey alkuzad I configured the sudoers file so that the command is passwordless. The command is still not executed from the Flask app though.

Comment: I do not have more clues, you have to be more precise http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#beprecise

Comment: I added more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a bad idea to me. Providing your web app `sudo` access and making that call publicly available screams liability.

Instead here are a couple of other options:

**Automate it with a ssh command**

You can actually run a command over SSH without having to do a full login yourself. You can continue to use the user you are using at the moment, but set up [passwordless login](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2%60) to use a public-private key pair.

Then call `ssh -i /path/to/keyfile username@server 'sudo reload halo'`

**Auto reload with gunicorn**

`gunicorn` has a [`--reload`](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/19.0/settings.html#reload) option builtin you should consider using as well.

Comment: Thanks. I will use this solution.